# How to check whether firewall allows traffic on specific port but not listening on the port

Tags: firewalls, ports

I have client / server and there is a firewall between them.
The server is listening on a port and I want to check if this port is allowed by the firewall.

 I can only know the ports that the machine is listening on using netcat, but I want to know if the server port is allowed to pass.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use nmap correctly](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47158/use-nmap-correctly)

Comment: This question is basically "how do I port scan" - see [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47158/use-nmap-correctly/47159) for some simple basics, and maybe google 'nmap tutorial'

Comment: If it's available, use Telnet.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. You are sitting on a client and trying to access a server which is behind a firewall. You want to know whether the connection from the client to the server will go past the firewall on a specific port. If that is what you want then you can use nmap like this - nmap -Pn -sT -p T:80 www.google.com. This will send a Syn packet to the destination only on that specific port. If you want to test a UDP port use U:53 instead of T:80

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution without having to fire up your server application would be to use [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).

```
user@1.2.3.4 ~$ nc -vl 1234
Connection from 9.8.7.6 port 1234 [tcp/*] accepted

user@9.8.7.6 ~$ nc 1.2.3.4 1234
```

Please forgive me if this does not answer your question as this does create a listening socket. I just wanted to share this as an option.